# Paths in tsconfig not found

Tags: angular, typescript

I have multiple project in same Angular 8 app.
In "root" `tsconfig.json` I add paths for `@models`

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "paths": {
      "@models": ["projects/shared/models"]    <=== this
    }
  },
```

I Import from `index.ts` barrel

```
export * from "./users/user-profile.model";
export * from "./users/users.model";
```

When I try In any component import model from `@models`

```
import { IUser } from "@models";
```

I get error

> error TS2307: Cannot find module '@models'

But when I try to import it directly from the barrel, working ok

In every of my project, I also have `tsconfig.app.json`, but I only add the path to the root

Comment: ```"@models": ["projects/shared/models"]```  shoulde be replaced with  ```"@models": ["projects/shared/models/index.ts"]``` in tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 1):

Problem was in VS code, after multiple restarts, everything is working

Answer (score 0):

`"@models": ["projects/shared/models"]` should be replaced with `"@models": ["projects/shared/models/index.ts"]` in tsconfig.json file or you can write like below also

```
  "@models": [
    "projects/shared/models/*"
  ],
```

Comment: can u please share a stackblitz link for further investigation?

Comment: i will try, but this is very big app, i try to make example

Comment: Can you share the tsconfig.app.json. Please check what is the base url set in tsconfig.app.json also

Comment: this is the tsconfig.app.json {
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": ["src/main.ts", "src/polyfills.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/test.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts"]
}

Comment: I tried in my local and it works. Try restarting your editor please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"paths": {
      "@models/*": ["projects/shared/models/*"]
    }
```

After Updating `tsconfig.json`, restart the application